# javascript check for not null

Tags: javascript

Below is a code snippet, where we retrieve a form value.
Before further processing check if the value is not null..

```
var val = document.FileList.hiddenInfo.value;
alert("val is " + val);  // this prints null which is as expected
if (val != null)
{
   alert("value is "+val.length); // this returns 4
}
else
{
   alert("value* is null");
}
```

Any ideas why it happens so.. ??

Comment: !== instead of !=

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It's because val is not `null`, but contains `'null'` as a string.

Try to check with 'null'

```
if ('null' != val)
```

For an explanation of when and why this works, see [the details below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34817844/884640).

Comment: should be if (null != val) somehow it was not working with the quotes

Comment: Mr.x in the question, null was as string ...your case is probably different

Answer (score 168):

this will do the trick for you

```
if (!!val) {
    alert("this is not null")
} else {
    alert("this is null")
}
```

Comment: while technically this works, a double not (!!) is a programming faux-pas. It is really the equivalent of `if(val)`, which is much clearer to read. I would stick to that (fyi Ujwal, !!val should technically work in C or C++ also) see here for javascript 'truthiness' values: https://janosch.woschitz.org/javascript-equality-comparison/

Comment: how about if(!Boolean(val))

Comment: !! is just a double negative, so it's literally saying if(val.exists). I still like the way it looks though!

Comment: this will fail if `val = 0` since `!!0` evaluates to false

Comment: Hm. why console.log(!!null) prints false in FF?

Comment: It's not a simple double negative. It's a transforming double negative. You are basically transforming the variable to a boolean. There's a lot to say on the subject but suffice it to say that in cases where your variable is `0`, `false`, `null`, `undefined` or some such value that resolves to `true` with one !, you're going to get `false` for !!. It should be used sparingly if at all.

Comment: Fails if val = 0 @punkrockpolly - Thanx

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer has so many votes. `!!` converts the value to a boolean, so like the others stated it is not sufficient for checking against NULL in particular since all falsy values will go into the else case

Comment: This is just wrong. Using this without understanding will cause a lot of bugs. If `val` is any falsy value like `0` (zero), `false`, `undefined` etc.. this will pass validation, but we are only looking for `not null`

Answer (score 141):

There are 3 ways to check for "not null". My recommendation is to use the Strict Not Version.

## 1. Strict Not Version

```
if (val !== null) { ... }
```

The *Strict Not Version* uses the [Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6). The `!==` operator has faster performance than the `!=` operator, because the Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm doesn't typecast values.

## 2. Non-strict Not Version

```
if (val != null) { ... }
```

The *Non-strict Not Version* uses the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3). The `!=` operator has slower performance than the `!==` operator, because the Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm typecasts values.

## 3. Double Not Version

```
if (!!val) { ... }
```

The *Double Not Version* has [faster performance](https://jsperf.com/tfm-not-null/6) than both the *Strict Not Version* and the *Non-Strict Not Version*. However, the `!!` operator will [typecast "falsey" values](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) like `0`, `''`, `undefined` and `NaN` into `false`, which may lead to unexpected results, and it has worse readability because `null` isn't explicitly stated.

Comment: It's very odd. `!!val` worked for me but `val!==null` have not. Why is it?

Comment: @TheLogicGuy - What is the datatype of `val`? `console.log(typeof val)`.

Comment: number. the code removes "bad" values from the array (null,0 etc). Here is the code:http://pastebin.com/L7Z1BtuL

Comment: @TheLogicGuy - Your actual problem has nothing to do with null.
NaN isn't filtering correctly - that will always return true. This should work: !(isNaN(val) && (typeof val !== "undefined")). In Javascript there's a concept known as "Truthy" and "Falsey". The double-not operator `!!` will remove more than just `null`. It will convert `NaN` and `undefined` into false as well. And that's why your array filters correctly when using the double not-operator `!!`.

Answer (score 33):

Use `!==` as `!=` will get you into a world of nontransitive JavaScript truth table weirdness.

Comment: Unless you want to specifically check for `undefined` or `null`.  In which case `val != null` will return `true` for `undefined` or `null` but not for other falsey values like `0`.

Comment: Imo there's one situation where `!=` is a legitimate use case. And that's exaclty when comparing with `null` - given you actually don't care whether a missing value ended up as `null` or as `undefined`,

Answer (score 8):

You should be using the strict `not equals` comparison operator `!==` so that if the user inputs `"null"` then you won't get to the `else`.

Comment: Susan Null would not be happy if her name was not accepted in a data entry form lol

Answer (score 8):

Check https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/253723

```
if(value) {
}
```

will evaluate to true if value is not:

```
null
undefined
NaN
empty string ("")
0
false
```

Comment: Just because a value is 'truthy' does not mean its the value you need.

Comment: not a good solution if you are checking if a number is assigned (0 will evaluate to false, even though the value is not null). Better check directly if the value is equal to null (value === null)

Comment: if (value) means that you're not accepting 0 as a positive value, checking if number is 0 is a very different use case (i mentioned that 0 here is accepted so i can't see how did fit this solution to your case)

Answer (score 5):

It is possibly because the value of `val` is actually the string `"null"` rather than the value `null`.

Answer (score 5):

This should work fine..

```
   if(val!= null)
    {
       alert("value is "+val.length); //-- this returns 4
    }
    else
    {
       alert("value* is null");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to include 0 as a valid value:

```
if (!!val || val === 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
if (val) {
    alert("Not null");
} else {
    alert("Null");
}
```

Comment: Will not work for 0 (zero), undefined, false, "" (empty string) or any falsy value